# What's the proper usage of apostrophes in plural abbreviations?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, apostrophe

If I were to abbreviate the word *university*, I would most likely write *uni* — or would *uni’* be more correct?

If I wanted to say *universities*, would I write *unis* or *uni’s*?

My gut instinct would be to go with *unis*, but are there any particular rules regarding this?

Comment: Using _uni_ to mean _university_ seems to be something that only German speakers of English say, in my experience.

Comment: Please scan through the links under 'RELATED' in the right hand column on this page.

Comment: *uni* is not a recognized English abbreviation. Use **Univ.** You may abbreviate the plural as 'Univs.'

Comment: @Kris Thanks for correcting my abbreviation of university, although you didn't really answer the question, and those in the related column don't either.

Comment: @200_success Although, as Kris points out it isn't correct english, it is used almost exclusively in an informal context in my experience.